# Неправильный JSON (не парсится)

Tags: json, ruby

Есть такой JSON (написал его сам, в нем то и проблема).

```
{
    "services":
    {
        "CategoryName1" : ["Service1", "Service2", "Service3"],
        "CategoryName2" : ["Service1", "Service2", "Service3"]
    }
}
```

И пытаюсь распарcить его

```
json = JSON.load(File.new("db/service_seed.json"))
service_seed = JSON.parse(json)
```

Первая строка выполняется нормально, на второй выполняется ошибка:

> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Погодите, у вас же JSON.load уже все распарсил в хэш? Вам зачем его дальше парсить?

```
require 'json'

json = JSON.load(File.new("db/service_seed.json"))
puts json.class
p json
```